# I cant find my certificate when i am running ' python manage.py runserver_plus --cert /etc/ssl/cert '

Tags: python, django, pyopenssl

i am getting filenotfound error when i am trying to access my ssl certificate because i want my local host run on https

python manage.py runserver_plus --cert /etc/ssl/cert

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\utils.py", line 59, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\commands\runserver_plus.py", line 260, in handle
    self.inner_run(options)
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\management\commands\runserver_plus.py", line 337, in inner_run
    ssl_context = make_ssl_devcert(os.path.join(dir_path, root), host='localhost')
  File "E:\final3\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 524, in make_ssl_devcert
    with open(cert_file, "wb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/ssl\\cert.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert /etc/ssl/cert`

but then

> `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/ssl\cert.`

I see from your paths that you're on Windows. `/etc/` is a *nix/Linux-only directory, so you shouldn't be trying to place your SSL certificate there.

Try `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert E:\final3\ssl` after creating an `ssl` directory in the `final3` folder.

Finally, why on earth do you want an SSL certificate to access your **local computer?** Nobody can access your information but people on your network.

Comment: i need this certificate only for facbook login in my web app because it requires https instead of http so i followed a tutorial but  unfortunately and i cant find the certificates path,thanks for your help